# Strange exception in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I developed the extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Get<T>(this DataContext dataContext) where T : class
{
    return dataContext.GetTable<T>();
}
```

Then I tried to use it:

```
dataContext.Get<XDbCurrency>().
Where(c => c.Id == XCurrencyId.USD).
SelectMany(
    c =>
        dataContext.Get<XDbCurrencyRate>().
        Where(cr =>
            cr.CurrencyId == c.Id &&
            cr.StartOn <= DateTime.UtcNow &&
            cr.EndOn > DateTime.UtcNow).
        Take(1),
    (c, cr) => cr).
ToArray();
```

I get the exception ``` Member access 'XCurrencyId CurrencyId' of 'X.XDbCurrencyRate' not legal on type 'System.Data.Linq.Table``1[X.XDbCurrencyRate]. ``` When I change `Get` back to `GetTable` - everything works! When I change the return type of `Get` from `IQueryable<T>` to `Table<T>` - it crashes.

**UPDATE.** I created `XDataContextBase` class, moved `Get` method there, inherited DBML-generated `XDataContext` from `XDataContextBase` - unfortunately it does not help. Magic!!

**UPDATE.** `this.GetTable<XDbCurrencyRate>` works, `this.XDbCurrencyRates` works, `this.Get<XDbCurrencyRate>` not works either `Get` is extension method or method in base class. By the way, internally `this.XDbCurrencyRates` is implemented absolutely like my `Get`. Magic!!

**UPDATE.** Looks like Linq-to-SQL supports only two things: either direct call of `DataContext.GetTable<>` or call of any-named property that returns `System.Data.Linq.Table<XDbCurrencyRate>`. If I create `System.Data.Linq.Table<XDbCurrencyRate> Foo` - it works, but when I create `IQueryable<XDbCurrencyRate> Foo` - it crashes with `Queries with local collections are not supported.`. Magic!!

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want such an extension in the first place?

Comment: Let's assume it has an additional code not affiliated with Linq-to-SQL at all. I simplified my question.

Comment: And does it work if you remove the "additional code not affiliated with Linq-to-SQL at all"?

Comment: I posted minimal non-working code. It does not have any extra code and still not working.

Comment: What of you slap on a `select` in you method? `return dataContext.GetTable<T>().Select(x => x);` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the initial `Get` call is not part of the query tree. Just a normal method call. The second call is embedded in the tree and LINQ to SQL has no idea what that method means.

I know that EF would give up here immediately. I believe L2S is basically capable of running such a method locally and trying to inline the query that it returns. Here, that seems to now work out (or I'm wrong about that).

What I did was to create a custom LINQ provider that rewrites expression trees to execute such methods locally, inline their results into the query tree and then forward to LINQ to SQL. This is not trivial.

Maybe you can make `AsExpandable` from the so called "LINQ kit" (approximate spelling) work.

Comment: Interesting thing that if I create `XDataContextWrapper` class around `XDataContext`, put `IQueryable<T> Get<T>()` method there, and then call `wrapper.Get<>` - it will work as excepted, can you believe it?

Comment: But another thing stops to work - SQL function, which is implemented by code-generator as `[Function(Name="dbo.Foo", IsComposable=true)] public IQueryable<FooResult> Foo(....)`. It not works even if I pass it through wrapper.

Comment: I was using the DataContext wrapper for a looong time but then I stuck with SQL function. I decided to eliminate wrapper and convert some its methods to extensions. Now I forced to completely remove those methods and work on raw DataContext.

Comment: Or, you could slap `.AsExpandable` on every query and continue doing this. Should work. Btw, are you aware that L2S is obsolete? If you're getting started with this better use EF.

Comment: What about generated SQL? `.AsExpandable` will create two separate subqueries or will create `INNER JOIN` like I have before? I know about L2S and EF, L2S looks simpler and nicer ... I do not understand why L2S is abandoned, so nice technology as for me.

Comment: Right, L2S is nicer and more competently done. I'm stuck with it on a 100kloc codebase and EF still is not capable of taking over. Shameful.

Comment: AsExpandable inlines the subqueries and subexprssions. The underlying provider cannot tell the difference. Everything will work.